# how to add a sound after X clicks on Xcode

Tags: visual-c++, if-statement, onclick, xcode5, audio

I am trying to make an application that counts the number of clicks on a button, and plays a sound when the number of clicks is 10 ... I've tried a lot of different code, but it's not working. Any help is appreciated.

This is the .m file

What should I add inside the if statement?

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"
    @interface ViewController ()

     @end

    @implementation ViewController

    -(IBAction)Add{

     count++;


    number.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];
    if (count==10) {




     }

     }

    -(IBAction)Reset{
      count=0;
    number.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];

    }

  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     }

   - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```

And this is the .h file

```
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
       int count;

        @interface ViewController : UIViewController
        {
        IBOutlet UILabel *number;

         }

       -(IBAction)Add;
     -(IBAction)Reset;

         @end
```